# How to disable/remove Adobe tracker from the taskbar?

Tags: linux, startup, autostart, acrobat-reader

Unfortunately I need sometimes the Adobe pdf reader and can not use always one of the [free alternatives](http://pdfreaders.org/).

Now I recognized a new icon in the Mate taskbar 
[image: Adobe tracker alert]

Its tooltip says `Adobe Tracker Alert` and has two menu items

- Open Tracker
- Open Preferences

The latter opens a preferences dialog from Adobe Acrobat 9.5.5 which was installed as binary via the official gentoo packages.

[image: preferences dialog from Adobe Acrobat 9.5.5]

But I could not find a way to disable this function and I have no idea what this tracker does. 
I do not want to have more features than necessary from a closed source program.

**How can I remove / disable this tracker and what is it meant to do on my system?**

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer to this question in [this post on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1576830)

First I did `ps -ef | grep Adobe` and found a process

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/SynchronizerApp-binary -c`
```

Killing this process got rid of the icon in my taskbar.